# "Lassen Sie uns" oder "Lassen wir uns"

Tags: grammaticality

I am reading a novel where one character tells the other he wants to speak with him "unter vier Augen". The person asked then replies:

> "Lassen Sie uns in mein Büro gehen."

That seems OK, but in my experience the reply should have been:

> "Lassen **wir** uns in mein Büro gehen."

Are both correct? And if so is there a difference in meaning?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the example from the question, the only correct version is

> Lassen Sie uns in mein Büro gehen.

This suggestion to do something is always addressed to the other person(s) and implies that the speaker intends to do this as well.

*"Lassen Sie uns..."* addresses one or more persons formally. Informal variants are *"Lass uns..."* or *"Lasst uns..."*.

See (*1) https://www.dwds.de/wb/lassen#d-1-8

The phrase *"lassen wir uns"* can be used in a different context with the meaning to have something done by someone else or by a machine...

See (*2) https://www.dwds.de/wb/lassen#d-1-1

... or to allow something for us to happen.

See (*3) https://www.dwds.de/wb/lassen#d-1-2

There are examples where both variants are possible without changing anything else, resulting in different meaning (*1) or (*2). (I did not find an example where the meaning (*3) is involved.)

> Lassen Sie uns nach Hause fahren. = *Let us drive home. / Let us go home by a vehicle.*

The speaker suggests that the addressed person(s) and the speaker will do something.

> Lassen wir uns (von jemandem) nach Hause fahren. = *Let's have someone drive us home.*

The speaker suggests to have someone else do something.

(This variant is not possible in the example from the question because "gehen" cannot have a passive meaning in contrast to "fahren".)

Comment: In phrases like *Lassen wir uns nicht zu einer überstürzten Entscheidung hinreißen* neither a machine nor somebody else is involved.

Comment: @guidot I added this meaning as well, but I didn't come up with a minimal pair with this meaning.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Bodo's answer, maybe it helps to analyze the expression grammatically for better understanding. The grammatical structure is completely the same in English as it is in the German translation.

> Let us go to my office.

Note that it is *us*, not *we*. *Let* is an imperative, *us* is an object.

So the other person is asked to *let* someone do something, namely let *us* go into the office.

The German translation with *du* is completely straightforward:

> Lass uns in mein Büro gehen.

*Lass* is the imperative form of *lassen*, *uns* is the accusative of *wir*.

With formal "Sie", this becomes:

> Lassen Sie uns in mein Büro gehen.

Again, the other person is asked to *let* someone, namely *us*, go into the office.

What might make this confusing from an English speaker's perspective is the imperative for formal "Sie". It might look strange because formal "Sie" is based on third person plural ("sie" = they) in German.

> Geh in mein Büro! <=> Go to my office!
> Gehen Sie in mein Büro! <=> Go to my office! (Grammatically: "Go they to my office!")

Comment: I suggest adding the personal pronoun *du* in brackets in the corresponding examples, such as: "*Geh (du) in mein Büro!*" This might help to better understand the structure of the imperative by analogy to the plural ("*Gehen Sie in mein Büro!*"). After all, you can add that it is usually omitted in singular, but not in plural.